# Не получается создать функцию

Tags: java, функции

Хочу создать функцию в которую передается два значения. Первое это переменная типа String, вторая типа int. Функции нужно создать переменную с именем  переменной String, и значением int и вывести в консоль. Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Поясните фразу: `"Функции нужно создать переменную с именем переменной String"` - что это значит? Имя переменной должно совпадать с именем класса `String`? Или нужно динамически через рефлексию создать поле класса с типом `int` и именем, которое пришло 1м параметром?

Comment: "Не получается создать функцию" - что конкретно не получается? С чем возникли сложности?

Comment: Смотрите, есть функция сдопустим public void create(String str, int num) { нужно создать переменную с именем str и значением num }

Answer (score 0):

> переменную с именем переменной String

Безусловно это ключевое в данном вопросе.

По идее это невозможно, правда в Java 8 как будто бы реализована возможность с помощью рефлексии вытянуть имя [переменной в параметре](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118) - но как то я то ли плохо искал, то ли не нашел в документации как это делается.

Гораздо проще это можно реализовать если передавать параметром класс, типа

```
class MyParameter {
   String stringParam;
   int intParam;

   MyParameter(String stringParam, int intParam) {
      this.stringParam=stringParam;
      this.intParam=intParam;
   }
}

public void myFunc(MyParam myParam) {
    Field fields[] = MyParam.class.getDeclaredFields(); //список полей класса
    for(Field field:fields) {
        if (String.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType()))
           System.out.println(field.getName()+" "+myParam.intParam); //печатаем имя строковой переменной и значение целой переменной
    }
}
```

**Традиционный дисклеймер:** код не проверенный, я не компилятор, даю только общее направление

Comment: Нда... ТС сам не понимает своего вопроса :)